# Unable to use function's Variable in a sub in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the below VBA code on my ms-access form

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim obj1 As Object
    Dim GetEmpID As String
    Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
    GetEmpID = DLookup("[EmpID]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
    Set obj1 = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.EmpName.Value = GetUserName
    Me.EmpID.Value = GetEmpID
End Sub
```

I am able to get the value using `GetUserName` in my `Load()` sub but unable to get the value using `GetEmpID`.

What can be the possible reason? And how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GetEmpID is a variable declared inside the scope of the GetUserName Function and is inaccessible outside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Create module level variables, which you set in the function (now a sub, since it is returning no value)

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Dim UserName as String
 Dim EmpID as String

 Public Sub GetValues()
  Dim obj1 As Object

  Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  UserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
  EmpID = DLookup("[EmpID]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
  Set obj1 = Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call GetValues() 'Invoke the function to set values
    Me.EmpName.Value = UserName 'retrieve values from module level variables
    Me.EmpID.Value = EmpID
 End Sub
```

Option 2: Create ByRef variables.

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Public Sub GetValues(ByRef UserName as String, ByRef EmpID as String) 
  Dim obj1 As Object

  Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  UserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
  EmpID = DLookup("[EmpID]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
  Set obj1 = Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim UserName as String
   Dim EmpID as String
    Call GetValues(UserName, EmpId) 'Invoke the function to set values of local variables.
    Me.EmpName.Value = UserName 'retrieve values from function scoped variables.
    Me.EmpID.Value = EmpID
 End Sub
```

Warning: typing from memory. minor corrections may be needed.

Comment: thanks for the solution, this looks exactly what i wanted. Both the methods looks perfect, but can you please tell me which would be the best option if there are multiple users using the same file simultaneously from the shared folder ? and its a form meant for data entry by multiple users. What can be the posssible error if i use any of the above mentioned option, if any ?

Comment: For multiple users, they recommend splitting an Access db into a "front end" which each user will have on their local machine, and a "backend" which is the data that lives on the network share. see http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/databasesplitter/  and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304932/how-to-manually-split-a-access-database-in-microsoft-access

Comment: thaks @jeremy fo this suggestion however, we focusing on eliminating number of files in our office in our shared folder hence provide each user a copy would not be a good idea for us. However, I have disabled most of the access functionalities for them for that file. So i was hoping if it can be done in a more efficient way.

Comment: totally up to you. having multiple folks in a single access db is a bad idea. You'll find out the pain soon enough should you continue on this route. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the advice mate, can you also please give some examples of what kind of problem i Might face if I conitnue doing this for few months.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the ByRef in your function.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GetUserName(ByRef GetEmpID as string) as string
dim obj1 as object

Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
GetEmpID = DLookup("[EmpID]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")

If not obj1 is nothing then
    Set obj1 = Nothing
End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim GetEmpID as string

GetEmpID = "None"

Me.EmpName.value = GetUserName(GetEmpID)
Me.EmpID.Value = GetEmpID
End Sub
```

The ByRef passes the address that is used to store the variable in memory. Once the address is passed instead of just the value, the any changes that happen to the address will be made to the variable across the project.

Please see website below for more detailed description of ByVal and ByRef:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, lemme try this method. Can you also suggest if there would be any possible error if i use the above code, as the form I am using is an access file which will be used by mutiple users through shared folder simultaneously !